# Can a Druid/Wizard share wizard spells on his companion? Or druid spells with his familiar?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, druid, multi-classing, wizard

As the title; I'm not seeing anything against it, I just know a lot of class abilities are limited to the class they're from normally. As a Druid 2/Wizard 1, could a character share say... *mage armor* with their animal companion? Or *cure light wounds* on their familiar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> At the druid’s option, she may have **any spell** (but not any spell-like ability) she casts upon herself also affect her animal companion.

> At the master’s option, he may have **any spell** (but not any spell-like ability) he casts on himself also affect his familiar.

Any spell means any spell, including those from other classes. Yes, you can do this.